# Dynamic calculation of difference between 2 rows in R using values from 1st 6 columns

Tags: r

I have a data with 8 rows and 41 columns. The columns headers are time series from 8/1/2015-12/1/2018 and the rows are from 7/1/2015-2/1/2016.

I am creating a new table where the ---
1st row would be difference of first 2 rows.Each row would comprise sum of values of columns from 9/1/2015-2/1/2016. 
For 2nd row the calculation would be difference of 2nd and 3rd row. Each row would comprise sum of values of columns from 10/1/2015-3/1/2016.
For 3rd row it would be difference of 3rd and 4th row. Each row would comprise sum of values of columns from 11/1/2015-4/1/2016.

```
Column       Row       values
8/1/2015    7/1/2015    25

9/1/2015    7/1/2015    20

10/1/2015   7/1/2015    22

11/1/2015   7/1/2015    13

12/1/2015   7/1/2015    16

1/1/2016    7/1/2015    18

2/1/2016    7/1/2015    10

3/1/2016    7/1/2015    23

4/1/2016    7/1/2015    14

5/1/2016    7/1/2015    32

6/1/2016    7/1/2015    17

7/1/2016    7/1/2015    11

8/1/2016    7/1/2015    12

9/1/2016    7/1/2015    19

10/1/2016   7/1/2015    20

11/1/2016   7/1/2015    33

12/1/2016   7/1/2015    20

8/1/2015    8/1/2015    14

9/1/2015    8/1/2015    25

10/1/2015   8/1/2015    19

11/1/2015   8/1/2015    18

12/1/2015   8/1/2015    22

1/1/2016    8/1/2015    20

2/1/2016    8/1/2015    17

3/1/2016    8/1/2015    18

4/1/2016    8/1/2015    25

5/1/2016    8/1/2015    23

6/1/2016    8/1/2015    28

7/1/2016    8/1/2015    22

8/1/2016    8/1/2015    20

9/1/2016    8/1/2015    24

10/1/2016   8/1/2015    31

11/1/2016   8/1/2015    27

12/1/2016   8/1/2015    24
```

Similarly the calculation needs to continue from 3/1/2016-8/1/2016 and so on.

Thanks

Code that I have used

```
newdata2_reshape <- reshape(newdata2,
                       timevar = c("Column"),
                       idvar = c("Row"),
                       direction = "wide")
newdata2_reshape$date<-newdata2_reshape$Row[1]

newdata2_reshape$diff_in_days<- difftime
(newdata2_reshape$Row ,newdata2_reshape$date , units = c("days"))
newdata2_reshape$months<-ifelse(newdata2_reshape$diff_in_days >=28 & 
newdata2_reshape$diff_in_days <59,1,
ifelse(newdata2_reshape$diff_in_days>=59 & 
newdata2_reshape$diff_in_days<89,2,
ifelse(newdata2_reshape$diff_in_days>=89 
& newdata2_reshape$diff_in_days<120,3,
ifelse(newdata2_reshape$diff_in_days>=120 & 
newdata2_reshape$diff_in_days<150,4,
ifelse (newdata2_reshape$diff_in_days>=150 &
newdata2_reshape$diff_in_days<181,5,

                                                                                                                                                            ifelse(newdata2_reshape$diff_in_days>=181 & newdata2_reshape$diff_in_days<212,6,
ifelse(newdata2_reshape$diff_in_days>=212 & newdata2_reshape$diff_in_days<242,7,
ifelse(newdata2_reshape$diff_in_days>=242 & newdata2_reshape$diff_in_days<273,8,
ifelse(newdata2_reshape$diff_in_days>=273 & newdata2_reshape$diff_in_days<303,9,
ifelse(newdata2_reshape$diff_in_days>=303 newdata2_reshape$diff_in_days<334,10,
ifelse(newdata2_reshape$diff_in_days>=334 newdata2_reshape$diff_in_days <365,11,
 ifelse (newdata2_reshape$diff_in_days>=365,12,0))))))))))))

                                                                                         Now I have values against diff in days from 1 to 7 in my data
```

So if my value is 1,I should do a sum of 2nd to 7th column and subtract it from sum of 2nd to 7th column of previous row

if my value for date is 2 then I should do a sum of 3rd to 8th column and subtract it from sum of 3rd to 8th column of previous row.

Comment: Please illustrate with data and code.

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work?

Comment: I have tried calculating the sum and the difference in cell values between 2 rows. However I am not able to do it dynamically as the row changes